# run cgal example using qt creator error

Tags: c++, qt-creator, fedora, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm a beginner in using CGAL library ,I'm working on qt creator at Fedora OS,
I built and configured CGAL package , then created console app and try this example (which installed with CGAL package):

```
// Author(s) : Camille Wormser, Pierre Alliez

#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_triangle_primitive.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;

typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Ray_3 Ray;
typedef K::Line_3 Line;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Triangle_3 Triangle;

typedef std::list<Triangle>::iterator Iterator;
typedef CGAL::AABB_triangle_primitive<K, Iterator> Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<K, Primitive> AABB_triangle_traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<AABB_triangle_traits> Tree;

int main()
{
Point a(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
Point b(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Point c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
Point d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

std::list<Triangle> triangles;
triangles.push_back(Triangle(a,b,c));
triangles.push_back(Triangle(a,b,d));
triangles.push_back(Triangle(a,d,c));

// constructs AABB tree
Tree tree(triangles.begin(),triangles.end());

// counts #intersections
Ray ray_query(a,b);
std::cout << tree.number_of_intersected_primitives(ray_query)
    << " intersections(s) with ray query" << std::endl;

// compute closest point and squared distance
Point point_query(2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
Point closest_point = tree.closest_point(point_query);
std::cerr << "closest point is: " << closest_point << std::endl;
FT sqd = tree.squared_distance(point_query);
std::cout << "squared distance: " << sqd << std::endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**and then I added the header files to the project :**
"Simple_cartesian.h" -  "AABB_tree.h" - "AABB_traits.h" - "AABB_triangle_primitive.h"

**but while running the project I faced these errors:**
:-1: error: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'

:-1: error: note: '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv' is defined in DSO /lib64/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 so try adding it to the linker command line

/lib64/libboost_system.so.1.54.0:-1: error: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

***any help please?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line into your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lboost_system
```

Of course, assuming that you have downloaded and installed [boost.system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) library.